# How did Hanuman meet Sugriva

Tags: ramayana, hanuman, sugriva

Please can someone explain, from Valmiki Ramayana, how and when Hanuman met Sugriva first time and why he took up service to Sugriva.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hanumanji was placed in the service of Sugriva by Surya after Hanumanji finished his academics from him.

The chronology of Hanumanji’s life is:

1. Birth and attempting to gobble the sun and Rahu (VR Uttarakanda 35.24)
2. The naughtiness with the sages and consequent curse to forget his powers. (VR Uttarakanda 36.29-35)
3. His studies under the guidance of Surya (VR Uttarakanda 36.46-49)

Now Sugriva was the son of Surya from Riksharajas. On Sugriva’s birth and completion of Hanumanji’s studies under Surya, Surya placed Hanumanji (who was Surya’s student) in service of Sugriva:

> “Those two powerful monkeys being born, Indra conferred a lasting golden chain on Bali and returned to his own abode and, **having engaged Hanuman, the Wind-god’s son, in the service of Sugriva, the Sun-god** too returned to the Celestial Region.
> -*VR Uttarakanda Sarga 37b*

And of course, then Riksharajas becomes king of Kishkindha and the relation between Sugriva and Hanumanji is described as:

> Hanuman and Sugriva were as one and there was no difference between them; they loved each other as do Agni and Anila.
> -*VR Uttarakanda Sarga 36.40*

Comment: "he placed Hanumanji (who was Surya’s student) in service of Sugriva"... Who is "he" here? @archit

Comment: @Kanthri Read first line of the answer and the below quote, it’s Surya